# Preact Compat incompatibility in Jest tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, preact

I'm using preact 8.4.2 and have preact-compat as well.

I'm using `linkifyjs/react` to render links in text. This works fine in development, but my tests are failing when trying to import the React-dependent `linkifyjs/react' library with this error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: type
        at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)

      1 | import {h, Component, createRef} from 'preact';
    > 2 | import Linkify from 'linkifyjs/react';
        | ^
```

I'm really not sure what this error means, and I'm confused because preact-compat is supposed to allow use of libraries with React dependencies. The stack trace points to preact-compat/src/index.js:60 which has:

```
Object.defineProperty(VNode.prototype, 'type', {
    get() {
        return this.nodeName;
    },
    set(v) {
        this.nodeName = v;
    },
    configurable: true
});
```

Comment: Which version of preact are you using? If its 10, it should be `preact/compat` instead of `preact-compat`.

Comment: using the stable version - 8.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. What caused the problem for me was that both `preact-compat` and `enzyme-adapter-preact-pure` were trying to make a Preact vNode to look like a React element.

https://github.com/preactjs/enzyme-adapter-preact-pure/pull/62

This pull request for `enzyme-adapter-preact-pure` has fixed those issues for me. So with enzyme-adapter-preact-pure@^2.0.1 everything works like it should.